# MySQL update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update 2 of my database's fields according to user input.My code is something like this:

```
 <body>
<?php
 $db_server["host"] = "localhost"; //database server
$db_server["username"] = "root"; // DB username
$db_server["password"] = "mypass"; // DB password
$db_server["database"] = "mudb";// database name

$dbc = mysql_connect($db_server["host"], $db_server["username"], $db_server["password"]);
mysql_select_db($db_server["database"], $dbc);
$user =  $_COOKIE['mycookie'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$user'"; 
    $r = mysql_query( $q,$dbc);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    echo 'username: '.$row['username'], '<br/>';

    $password=$row['password'];
?>

<form method="post" id="changepasswordform" > 
<input type="password" id="newpassword" name="newpassword"/>
<input type="submit"  name="changepasswordbutton"  >  
       </form>

<?php

        echo 'email:        '.$row['email'], '<br/>'; 
        }
?>

<form method="post" id="changeemailform" >  

        <input type="text" id="newemail" name="newemail"/>

       <input type="submit" value="αλλαγή"  name="changeemailbutton"  >
       </form>

<?php
}


    if (isset($_POST['changepasswordbutton'])){

                       $newpassword=$_POST['newpassword'];
                $q2 = "UPDATE members SET password=$newpassword WHERE username='$user'"; 

                $r2 = mysql_query($q2,$dbc);

}   

if (isset($_POST['changeemailbutton'])){
                    $newemail=$_POST['newemail'];
                    $q3 = "UPDATE members SET email=$newemail WHERE username='$user'"; 
                $r3 = @mysql_query( $q3,$dbc);  
}
?>
</body>
```

However although my connection to my db is ok(SELECT displays results as expected) when i try to UPDATE , the values inside my db remain the same.I checked the values of $newpassword  and $newemail and they do contain the user inputs each time.What am i missing here?

Comment: **warning** your code is very susceptible to sql injection attacks!

Comment: you should also salt+hash your users passwords.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Did you notice that you have no curly brackets in your query strings for variables? The string variables in other string values should be quoted with `{}` like `UPDATE members SET password='{$newpassword}' WHERE username='{$user}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `''` (quotes) that supposed to surround the password field.
change:

```
UPDATE members SET password=$newpassword WHERE username='$user'
```

to:

```
UPDATE members SET password='{mysql_real_escape_string($password)}' 
WHERE username='{mysql_real_escape_string($user)}'
```

**IMPORTANT:**
And even though it's not related, please don't use `mysql_*` functions - it's deprecated and vulnerable to sql-injection. Better use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: this just makes me sick - sql injection warning!

Comment: @alfasin the *code* you provided is open to sql injection. Your note about `mysql_*` functions doesn't fix that.

Comment: To all of you: downvoting means: this answer is not useful. Now, is it ? have a great days fox.

Comment: If you edit `UPDATE members SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$user'` to be secure, I'll remove my -1 and replace it with a +1 if that helps.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes. The answer is perfectly valid, the issue was missing quotes. This is what's not working in the OP source code. Whatever the author is doing on his free time (opening security holes for instance)  is his own problem. He has been warned in the comments.

Comment: Promise kept :-) I may just be tired; I'll try to not be so quick on the draw in the future.

Comment: @MathieuImbert: The answer may be **valid**, that does not make it **useful**. If a user asked to parse HTML with regex, would you give him the answer? Or maybe try to educate him to not go down that path?

Comment: @Truth Depending on the situation. It's not possible to parse HTML using regular expressions, but some specific cases are answerable yes. I understand your point, I just think commenting the question or the answer would be a nicer way to prove your point instead of trashing an answer with angry downvotes.

Comment: First of all thanks to everyone for your answers(and Daniel i'm sorry if i made you sick man),the problem was actually the quotes at the password case.However the email field still remains not changed no matter if i use `''` or `mysql_real_escape_string`.As for the mysql_ you are all right of course,this is my first website and i saw it in an example online,i had no idea it was that bad.My next step will be to replace it,but i'd rather first find what's wrong with my current code.

Comment: @yiannis the same reason, you should add `''` around the email as well:  `"UPDATE members SET email='$newemail' WHERE username='$user'`. And  yiannis, try to ignore the rude behavior and still learn from their remark regarding the use of `mysql_*`. In my native language there's a saying that even a broken clock is showing the hour correctly twice a day ;)

Comment: @alfasin i want to thank you for your replies!it's always a nice surprise to see polite comments online!You sir,deserve your medals.of course i will stop using mysql_*,polite or rude all these comments are very correct.@all thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick and is save for sql injection (`mysql_real_escape_string`):

```
 $q2 = "UPDATE members SET 
   password='". mysql_real_escape_string($password) ."' 
   WHERE username='". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."';
```

But off course you shouldn't use `mysql_*` anymore, I'm just giving an example for your specific case.